# Xiaomi stuck on the fastboot screen after failed EMUI update

Tags: fastboot, xiaomi, emui, xiaomi-mi9

Yesterday, I used the Xiaomi Mi 9 SE [`Updater`](https://adimorahblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Mi-9-update.jpg) app to update my EMUI version. After downloading the update zip file (2.8GB), the app warned me that it would "install the update, start in recovery mode and will ask for my password as the file system was encrypted" (I don't remember the message exactly).

The phone rebooted and got stuck on the Fastboot screen for more than a hour.

[image]

After that I rebooted multiple times with different ways (hold power button, hold power button + volume down, and hold power button + volume up and down) but just after the reboot it gets stuck on the Fastboot screen again.

I tried using the [Android platform tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) to try to reboot it but the result is the same, always stuck on the Fastboot screen.

```
$ sudo ./fastboot devices
f6da2608    fastboot

$ sudo ./fastboot reboot
Rebooting                                          OKAY [  0.000s]
Finished. Total time: 0.351s

$ sudo ./fastboot reboot recovery
Rebooting into recovery                            OKAY [  0.000s]
Finished. Total time: 0.352s
```

Do you have any solution to fix ?
If not, is it possible to do a factory reset ? I have backups for my data so no problem for me.

Comment: On a windows computer, you can try using the [MI flash tool](https://www.xiaomiflash.com/) to flash the firmware again

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it!

Comment: I couldn't make it work. I downloaded the Fastboot ROM, run the program and stuff but when the device was not recognized apparently. Each time I clicked "Flash" my device shut down.

Comment: Oops.. Maybe someone else can suggest a way out. Maybe, just maybe it will boot normally if you let battery drain out completely and then try to power up after charging?

Comment: Thanks anyway! Yeah I though the battery trick might do it too. I'm currently turning it on, then a few minutes later it shuts down, I turn it on again and so on all day long until the battery's dead. We'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [SDK platform tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) for the OS you have. Connect your device while in fastboot mode with your computer and run

```
fastboot devices
```

This should give you a result if your device is recognized. If your device does not show up make sure to install the proper drivers for it.
Then download the official fastboot ROM for your device. Unzip it and there should be a file in there with a name like `flash_all` (bat or sh depending on your OS run the appropriate one). Guides like [this](https://xiaomiui.net/how-to-flash-fastboot-rom-on-xiaomi-9902/) one can help for more details

Comment: Thanks for the `flash_all` script, I didn't see there was scripts embedded in the ROM file at first. Unfortunately I couldn't try it because I returned the phone to the shop (warranty was still active). If they can't fix it I will try this. Otherwise I will ask them what they did and post it here.

Comment: I got a refund because they couldn't fix it... Thanks anyway!